# Can we increase max size of the search box in usermanager?

Tags: user-management

Can we increase max size of the search box in usermanager? which currently only 20 character.

I am trying to implement this email search using link 
https://sitecorecontextitem.wordpress.com/2014/11/10/search-by-email-in-the-sitecore-user-manager/

but search box has only 20 character allowed in Usermanager

[image]

Comment: Using Dotpeek, have you tried to explore the Sitecore client library to see how it works?

Answer (score 3):

User Manager uses `/sitecore/layout/Layouts/Security/SecurityManager` layout.
Path to aspx page is `/sitecore/shell/Applications/Security/UserManager/UserManager.aspx`.
Layout uses Grid component from ComponentArt.Web.UI.dll
However, rendering process has difficult structure and works with hardcoded js files, including code for render search box:

```
window.ComponentArt_Grid.prototype.RenderSearchBox = function (_c1) {
    _c1[_c1.length] = "<div";
    if (this.SearchTextCssClass) {
        _c1[_c1.length] = " class=\"" + this.SearchTextCssClass + "\"";
    }
    _c1[_c1.length] = ">" + this.SearchText + " ";
    _c1[_c1.length] = "<input onsubmit=\"return false;\" onkeypress=\"return !" + this.Id + ".SearchCheckEnter(event)\" id=\"" + this.Id + "_searchBox\"";
    if (this.SearchBoxCssClass) {
        _c1[_c1.length] = " class=\"" + this.SearchBoxCssClass + "\"";
    }
    _c1[_c1.length] = " onkeyup=\"" + this.Id + ".SearchKeyHandler(event,this);\" type=\"text\" maxlength=\"20\" size=\"20\" value=\"" + this.SearchString + "\" /></div>";
};
```

I think that will be difficult to overwrite this logic.

Try to write your custom js for change maxlength and size attributes on `$(document).ready()`